# fsck -y breaks system

Tags: linux, fsck

I have a Red Hat development box and I recently had an outage where  the SAN disk was unavailable and and some applications were not running right so I ran fsck -y to check if the file system was ok, then I did a reboot. Now, I cannot even log in to the system. On startup, the console shows:

`Memory for crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) notwithin permissible range
Cannot setup NMI watchdog on CPU 0
Cannot setup NMI watchdog on CPU 1`

`...`

`INIT: No inittab file found`

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your rootfs is ext2-3-4, an e2fsck -f -y -C0 is a magic argument combo. Give it a try from a rescue cd/pendrive. If there are yet not repaired problems on your fs, it will fix them.

Second: some critical files on your system is dead. This time, /etc/inittab. This file doesn't changes very rapidly (practically never), so you can copy this from backup or from a fresh install (or from another redhat server).

If you have luck, another important files didn't destroyed.

---

Another tip: your /bin/bash is probably undamaged, so an init=/bin/bash would give you a wonderful rescue console.

Comment: You might want to follow up init=/bin/bash with a mount / -o remount or whatever the modern incantation is. Else you can not write to the filesystem which makes it hard to replace corrupt or missing files.